# cannot change width+height of image by javascript

Tags: javascript, image, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

I dynamically upload my picture.
My code should run also for IE9, and on the following code, I focus on IE9 only:

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <!-- <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" /> -->
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>  
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <title>Image preview example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var loadImageFile = (function () {
        if (navigator.appName === "Microsoft Internet Explorer") {
            return function () {
                $("#id_image").width(300);
                $("#id_image").height(300);
                $("#id_image").css("filter", "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(sizingMethod=image)");
                document.getElementById("id_image").filters.item("DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader").src = document.getElementById("imageInput").value;
$("#id_image").width(320); // ****** Problematic line
$('#id_image").height(350); // ****** Problematic line
            }
        }
    })();
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
    </style>
    </head>

    <body>

    <form name="uploadForm">
    <p><input id="imageInput" type="file" name="myPhoto" onchange="loadImageFile();" /><br />
    </form>
    <img id="id_image" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAD/ACwAAAAAAQABAAACADs%3D" onmousedown="return false" alt="Your picture"/>
    </body>
    </html>
```

1. Why must I declare width+height before line:
   document.getElementById("id_image").filters.item("DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader").src = document.getElementById("imageInput").value ?
2. I cannot put line (marked on asterisk : ****** Problematic line), because it doesn't change the width+height.

How can I change the width+height instead?

Thanks :)

Comment: please paste a running code on jsfiddle

Comment: I didn't understand what did you mean?
My code, is only a sample code, which I have problem to write it properly. That's why I am asking this forum.

I need to change width+height after the code of javascript, but I don't know what shall I write.

Comment: to debug and see whats wrong I would have liked to see a running version, now by just looking at it may be the line"  if (navigator.appName === "Microsoft Internet Explorer") returning a function but not executing it looks funny

Comment: does setting the css work? `$("#id_image").css({width:320,height:350});`

Comment: $("#id_image").css does the same thing ...

Sorry.
I didn't copy the code as well.
I have changed :sizingMethod=scale to sizingMethod=image.

I don't want to stretch the image.
What I do, indeed, put it in frame: 300x300.
I see what is the largest size (width or height), and calc the ratio 300/width or 300/height respectively.
Both width and height are multiply by the same ratio, so one of them is 300, and one of them is less.

To do this, I need to "know" first what is the size of the original image.
I do this, generaly, by putting width="auto", and height=

Comment: ... "auto", but this doesn't work.

How can I do the above?

Comment: Threat this issue closed, please.
(I shall create new one, with quite different code).

Comment: Consider this issue as closes, since I mentioned a solution on:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17012263/the-event-after-loading-image-on-ie9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a delay when changing image size till it changes on screen.

You can consider this issue as closed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to change attributes height and width of image, make sure that they are integers. If not use MAth.floor