# The event after loading image on IE9

Tags: javascript, html, image, internet-explorer-9

I am writing an internet site, using javascript, HTML for **IE9**.

I found solution to loading dynamically the image by:

```
document.getElementById("id_image").filters.item("DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader").src = document.getElementById("id_filepic").value
```

id_image related to the `<IMG>` and id_filepic related to `<input id="id_filepic" type="file">`

After the line:

```
document.getElementById("id_image").filters.item("DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader").src = document.getElementById("id_filepic").value
```

**what is the exact event** that occurs just after the image is shown on the html page (hence, the image has width + height), and how can I capture that event?

**It is important to me knowing the solution for IE9.**

Comment: Why do you want to dynamically load an image like that? There are several other solutions for preloading an image.

Comment: 1. I need loading dynamicaly, because I want to edit the loaded file, doing some manipulations to that file, before uploading it to server (with less traffics).
2. I need solution for IE9. FileReader is not working for IE9.

Comment: I'm sorry, but unless I'm terribly mistaken and IE9 has some serious security breach - which is unlikely - that solution does nothing like `FileReader`. So, to make things clear, do you want to load an image *from the client* or *the server*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't have to be after that line, since it will be asynchronous anyway, but here it is:

```
document.getElementById("id_image").filters.item("DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader").src = document.getElementById("id_filepic").value;
document.getElementById("id_image").addEventListener('load', (function(i) {
    return function() {
        console.log(i, 'loaded');
    }, false);
})(i));
```

Source: [Javascript Image onload event binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10121797/javascript-image-onload-event-binding)

Comment: Your code is not compiled, but I appriciate you efforts.
Also I succeeded at last, as the delay I added (my last post of this thread).
Problem solved, so you can consider this issue as closed.

Answer (score 1):

I want to participate my solution, I have found.

Well, the above is not compilable, and also 'onload' is not the correct event (**it is not fired after using the "filter" command**, as far as I investigated).

What I did is a little delay, with timeout command (about one second) like this :

```
    setTimeout(function () {
        alert("w: " + $("#id_image").width());
        alert("h: " + $("#id_image").height());
    }, 1000);
```

(even 100 milliseconds is enough, but I check that out for very large images. 1 second is quite big not to fall by code on large images).

After the delay, I could retrieve the image width and height with no problem.

That's complete this issue.

Comment: You could do a repeating timeout until said image has width and height you can track. That way you can avoid any big delay.